# How to replace column name in a string(python)?

Tags: python, string, list, dataframe, split

I have an issue with Replacing. So, I have a string and a list. The list contains the column names of the data frame and string contains few integers or letters with the column name. Now I want only the letters but not the column names in the string. So, for that, I have split the string basing on the (,) and tried to use replace to delete the column name but it is not working. Can anyone please help me out with this?

My df:

```
  a b c
0 d 2 4
1 f 4 5
2 r 9 0
```

My code:

```
values = "dffa,c20"
column = ['a','c']
value =values.split(',')
print(value)
z=[]
for i in column:
    for j in value:
        z.append(j.replace(i,''))
print(z)
```

output:

```
['dffa','c20']
['dff','c20','dffa','20']
```

expected output:

```
['dff','20']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to do a nested loop here; rather you want to to loop over two things at the same time, such that you have access to the *ith* element of each every iteration. You can use `zip` for that:

```
values = "dffa,c20"
column = ['a','c']
value = values.split(',')
z=[]

for element, letter in zip(value, column):
    z.append(element.replace(letter, ''))

print(z)
# ['dff', '20']
```

Comment: oh i get it. Thanks